# Open X hosted install error

Tags: cookies, openx

I wonder if anybody's had this problem before with installing Open X hosted. The error reads,

> Configuration of your webserver does not meet the requirements of the OpenX.

and then

> Browser cookies: You need to enable cookies before you can use OpenX

Thing is that cookies are enabled in my browser. Haven't had this issue before and the Open X documentation is pretty poor on this specific case.

Can you help?